# How to build script structure like Value = ClassName.Value?

Tags: c#

I have a class which name is `Color` and another class that it's name is `Object` that have a property with type of Color.

I want to assign this property like this:

```
 Object.Color = Color.Red
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `Color.Red` is a static property ([source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Color.cs,1073)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres a few ways you can do that, i'd probably suggest an `enum` for Color instead of a class:

```
using System;
namespace YourNameSpace
{
    public class Example
    {
        public static Colors Color;
    }

    public enum Colors { 
        Red,
        Blue
    }
}
```

In the above you would be able to set the static property `Object.Colors` as you have described:

```
Example.Color = Colors.Red;
```

Comment: Yes it's true but can you help me for write another line of code ? 
I have another property in Object that it's name is stringColor . How can i tell to compile when user changed the Color property that stringColor changing too 
for example if user write this code "object.color = color.red " the string automaticly changing to "#ff0000"

Comment: You could either switch to using String values instead of an enum:
public class Object
    {
        public static String Color;
    }

    public static class Colors {
        public const String Red = "#FF0000";
        public const String Blue = "#0000FF";//etc
    }

Comment: Or add in a getter code for the colorString property:
public static String ColorString { 
         get
            {
                switch (Color) {
                    case Colors.Red:
                        return "#FF00000";
                    case Colors.Blue:
                        return "#0000FF";
                    default:
                        return "unknown color...";
                }
            }
        }